# Where can I find an at least Semi-Comprehensive list of what biochemical reactions Acetyl-CoA participates in?

Tags: biochemistry, coa

Acetyl-CoA has a number of biochemical roles in the body and I'm curious as to whether anybody knows where I can find at least a semi-comprehensive list (i.e. comprising all the **major** roles in the human body it serves) of the biochemical reactions in which acetyl-CoA partakes in the human body.

Comment: Have you tried [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetyl-CoA)? All the _major_ ones should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing some fantastic resource, but my first thought is to send you to [KEGG](http://www.genome.jp).  Is that crazy?  Maybe, but a simple search for Acetyl-CoA in humans can give you tons of useful information, including GO terms, enzymes, genes, and, yes, [biochemical reactions](http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/search_pathway_text?map=hsa&keyword=acetyl-coa&mode=1&viewImage=true); just use the KEGG Pathways tool and specify humans (hsa).  You can click on each individual pathway for more information, such as the [cholinergic synapse](http://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?pathway+hsa04725).

[image: Cholinergic synapse pathway]

Comment: Are these reactions solely those that occur in the human body?

Comment: @BrentonHorne Wow sorry, I TOTALLY missed that!  It's now updated to be *homo sapiens* only.

Answer (score 0):

[Metacyc](http://metacyc.org/) is an excelent methabolic pathways database that includes all kind of organisms. Of course you can search for methabolic compound.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Lehninger's Principles of Biochemistry. Just search for Acetyl-coa in the index, and you will find it's roles in different aspects of the metabolism.